# A bound on a sum of five sines

Tags: calculus

If $0<x_{1},\ldots,x_{5}<\pi$ and $x_{1}+\ldots+x_{5}=\pi$,
is it true that $\sin x_{1}+\ldots+\sin x_{5}\le5\sin\frac{\pi}{5}$?

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange's method?

Answer (score 14):

Sine is a concave function on $[0, \pi]$ and so this follows from [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form) (4):

$$
\frac{\sin x_1 + \dotsc + \sin x_5}{5} \leq \sin\left( \frac{x_1 + \dotsc + x_5}{5} \right) = \sin \frac{\pi}{5}.
$$